# jQuery colorbox outside HTML with inline call

Tags: jquery, html, call, colorbox, inline

How can I get a response (for example a submit button) from a colorbox?

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".myclass").colorbox({width:"75%", height:"75%"});

    $('#btn').click(function(){
       $("#test").val("it works!");
    });
});

<body>
    <a class='myclass' href="1.html">Click to show the Colorbox</a>
</body>
```

1.html

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="submit" id="btn">
```

When I click on the submit button, nothing happens. How can I call the content of the colorbox and change the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".myclass").colorbox({
              width: "75%",
              height: "75%",
              onComplete: function () {
                $('#btn').click(function () {
                    $("#test").val("it works!");
                });
              }
           });           
         });
```